# Transaction over Data abstraction layer(DAL: Data Access Layer)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions, data-access-layer

Currently I am working on a DAL design, I have concern regarding managing transaction in Business Layer(BL) while keeping it unaware of DB technologies.

For ex: I have two DAOs

```
SalesOrderDAO, SalesOrderItemDAO
```

At some point in BL I would like to call update/create method on both in a transaction:

```
// some where in BL
  SalesOrderDAO soObj = new SalesOrderDAO();
  SalesOrderItemDAO soiObj = new SalesOrderItemDAO();

  //transaction start
  soiObj.create(); // it could be update as well
  soObj.update();  
  //on some condition transaction roll back

  //transaction end
```

How to acheive it?

Constraint:

- I am using Hibernate in DAL.
- I don't want my BL to be aware of Hibernate.
- Outside the DAL no one knows or should know what technology is being
  used to access the DB

(Am I missing something?)

Comment: Either create an abstraction yourself or use something like spring to transparantly handle your transaction boundaries.

Comment: Isn't DAL itself an abstraction?

Comment: You can use Spring Transactions in BL and call 2 DAOs.

Comment: Yes but for you data-access technology, your business layer is the abstraction for a lot of other things, and also the transaction/security/* boundary for your application. Something like spring can help you transparantly start/commit transactions.

Comment: @above thanks for reply I would have a look at spring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some research(after i received comment on question) I found spring have all I needed.

Say, in BL we have method: SomeBLMethod(), which does db operation using SalesOrderDAO, SalesOrderItemDAO and SomeBLMethod should be under transaction. 
We need to do following to make Transaction work:

- Get the object of SalesOrderDAO, SalesOrderItemDAO implementation using spring @Autowired attribute and perform db opration using these attributes.
- Make SomeBLMethod transactional using sprint @Transactional attribute.
- The implementation of SalesOrderDAO, SalesOrderItemDAO should use @Autowired SessionFactory object
- We also need to do some spring configuration.(which you can find in following url)

*Reference:*

- Example: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example
- Spring Transaction Management Doc: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/transaction.html

PS: I am adding this answer to help others.